# How to count the number of specific countries in XPath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to count the number of Russian speaking countries in the db. I started with

```
doc("countries.xml")//country[language="Russian"]/data(@name)
```

which gives me the names of the countries. I know I have to change "name" to "number" but how else can I get a number (6) instead of their names?
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count(doc("countries.xml")//country[language="Russian"])
```

**Alternatively, one couls use this XPath 2.0 - only expression:**

```
(doc("countries.xml")//country[language='Russian']/last())[1]
```